# Mapping buffer port in VHDL

Tags: mapping, vhdl, xilinx

I have aproblem with mapping the clock_div_1hz_aux with aux. 
I need to map those two ports (aux with clock_div_1hz_aux) and i don't know how. All the others are mapped, as I described in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHI5E.jpg)

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
entity controler is
Port ( reset : in STD_LOGIC;
clock : in STD_LOGIC;
....................
);
end controler;

component numarator
 Port (
 clk_num : in std_logic;
 reset_num : in std_logic;
 count : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
 );
 end component;

 component div_num
 Port (
 clock_div: in std_logic;
 reset_div : in std_logic;
 clock_div_1hz: buffer std_logic;
 clock_bla : out std_logic
 );
 end component;

num1: div_num PORT MAP(
 clock_div=>clock,
 clock_div_1hz => clk1hz,
 reset_div => reset

 );

num2: numarator PORT MAP(
 clk_num =>clk1hz,
 reset_num =>reset,
 count=>sensor_count
 );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `clock_div_1hz` a buffer? Isn't it a normal output?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using buffer in the component (div_num), you can declare the buffer as an output parameter and add an intermediate signal to the architecture of (div_num).
Just work with the intermediate signal in your design and assign it to the output parameter as a concurrent statement. For example (architecture of div_num):

```
architecture ... of ... is
begin
   output_parameter <= intermediate_parameter;
   process(...)
   begin
       -- use the intermediate_paramter instead of output_parameter
   end process;
end architecture;
```

After the above changes : It seems that you have 3 components (div_num , numerator , controler).

If you want to connect the output parameter (clock_div_1hz_aux) to (aux), just declare an interface signal (clk1hz_aux) and add it to the components (div_num and controler).

For example :

```
signal clk1hz_aux : std_logic;
component div_num
    Port(
        clock_div         : in  std_logic;
        reset_div         : in  std_logic;
        clock_div_1hz     : out std_logic;
        clock_div_1hz_aux : out std_logic
    );
end component;
component numarator
    Port(
        clk_num   : in  std_logic;
        reset_num : in  std_logic;
        count     : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end component;
component controler
    Port(
        clock : in std_logic;
        count : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
        aux   : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        -- declare output parameters of controler block
    );
end component;
num1 : div_num   PORT MAP(clock,reset,clk1hz,clk1hz_aux);
num2 : numarator PORT MAP(clk1hz,reset,sensor_count);
cntr : controler PORT MAP(clock,sensor_count,clk1hz_aux,reset,....);
```

Answer (score 0):

Amir, wouldn't be ok to use this type of mapping?

```
entity mapare is

Port ( 

     reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
     clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
     aux : in std_logic;
     ...........
    );
end mapare;


architecture Behavioral of mapare is

    component numarator is
        Port (
                clk_num : in std_logic;
                reset_num : in std_logic;
                count : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
                );
    end component;      

    component div_num is
        Port (
                clock_div: in std_logic;
                reset_div : in std_logic;
                clock_div_1hz: out std_logic;
                clock_div_1hz_aux: out std_logic

              );
        end component;  

    component controler is
        Port (
                clock: in std_logic;
                reset: in std_logic;
                aux : in std_logic;
                ...........
        );
        end component;  

signal sensor_count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
signal clk1hz: std_logic := '0';
signal aux1 : std_logic ;


begin
num1: div_num PORT MAP(
            clock_div=>clock,
            clock_div_1hz => clk1hz,
            reset_div => reset,
            clock_div_1hz_aux => aux1

            );

num2: numarator PORT MAP(
            clk_num =>clk1hz,
            reset_num =>reset,
            count=>sensor_count
            );


num3: controler PORT MAP (
         reset => reset,
         clock => clock,
         ...........
         aux=> aux1

        );

end Behavioral;
```